# click event on dynamically generated data attributes is not working

Tags: jquery

My problem  is `data-list`of `compare`class is generated dynamically,and i have implemented click handler on `compare` div.
On each click only `data-list` array changes so i am unable to figure out how to get updated data-list value on each click.

i know about delegate events but unable to figure out how to use here:

```
$('.compare').on('click','what-to-put-here?',function (e) {
var data = $(this).data('list');
alert(data);
});

<div  class="compare" id = "compare-box"  data-list = "">
  <div  class = "a"   style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 0px;font-size:13px">
    <h4>Compare Results (<span id="compare-items"></span>)</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle** [Guys Check My Code](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32483/)

Comment: Worst case you delegate to the document with `$(document).on('click', '.compare', function(){...`. See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: click event is not invoking

Comment: Are you sure that the `div` element shown has been added to the DOM when the JS code that wires up the handler is invoked?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: no the `div` element  with class 'a` is already there when page loads,only `data-list ` values has been changing dynamically on some other on click event.

Comment: Is the JS code inside of a `$(document).ready` handler?

Comment: @SteveDanner no its not in $(document).ready, this code is in separate file which i have been using in my index file by importing with script tag

Comment: Guys I have added the fiddle code

Comment: it's just bootstrap theme showing html there is no javascript or nothing useful, are you missing something ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to save changes,sorry for that, the fiddle is now working

Comment: `$('.compare').on('click','what-to-put-here?'` becomes `$('.compare').on('click','[data-list]'`

Comment: @Freedomn-m already tried and its not working,try fiddle

Comment: `$("#compare-box").attr('data-list',selectedList);` should be `$("#compare-box").data('list',selectedList);`

Comment: I was looking at the fiddle and there's no "what-to-put-here" - so your question doesn't match what you're actually asking.

Comment: Although your title is "dynamically generated", the event handlers are not on the dynamically generated attributes, so you don't need a delegated event handler (so ignore any comment/answer that says to use `$(document).on("click", ...`)

Comment: Confused me for a while, because both B and C have the value "2" so clicking ABC gives 122 :)  Updated working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32488/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have changed your fiddle little bit hope it will help :)

```js
var count = 0
var list = $("#compare-box").attr('data-list');
if(list)
{
 list = JSON.parse(list);
}
else
{
 list = [];
}
$(".compare-result").on('click',function(){
 //var list = 
 
 if($(this).is(":checked"))
 {
  if(count < 4)
  {
   var id = $(this).val();
   list.push(id);
   count++;  
  }
  else
  {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('input.compare-result').not(':checked').attr("disabled",true);
   alert('you can only compare 4 items');
  }
 }
 else
 {
  var id = $(this).val();
  count--;
  if(count < 4)
  {
   var index = list.indexOf(id);
   if (index > -1) {
    list.splice(index, 1);
   }
   $('input.compare-result').not(':checked').attr("disabled",false);
  }
  else
  {
   alert('error');
  } 
 }
 selectedList = JSON.stringify(list);
 $("#compare-items").html(count);
 console.log(selectedList);
});


//Main Problem Starts

$('.compare').on('click',function (e) {
  var data2 = '';
  $(".compare-result:checked").each(function(){
      data2 += $(this).val()+",";
  });
  data2 = data2.substring(0,data2.lastIndexOf(","));
  alert(data2);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="compare-result"  value = "1">a
<input type="checkbox" class="compare-result" value = "2">b
<input type="checkbox" class="compare-result" value = "3">c
<input type="checkbox" class="compare-result" value = "4">d
<input type="checkbox" class="compare-result" value = "5">e


<div  class="compare" id = "compare-box"  data-list = "">
  <div  class = "a"   style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 0px;font-size:13px">
    <h4>Compare Results (<span id="compare-items"></span>)</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah thanks for suggesting other alternative ,its working like a charm,thanks again

Answer (score 0):

follow below syntax

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.compare', function(){
    alert('what ever you want to do here');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nope its not working,still returning the first value from the first click event

Comment: can you please share fiddle or create code snippet so i can check the exact issue

Comment: I have added the fiddle link for this problem,u can have a look now

Comment: Sorry I forgot to save changes

Comment: have u seen that fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a `document.ready` handler to ensure that the elements are all loaded into the DOM when you attach your event handler.  It doesn't matter if its in a separate file, you can still use the handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.compare').on('click','what-to-put-here?',function (e) {
     var data = $(this).data('list');
     alert(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When *setting* data, you need to use

```
$(selector).data("name", value)
```

rather than `$(selector).attr("data-name", value)`

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32488/